# trying to get random value from two tables using mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM fixed_questions
WHERE examid = 15
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1

UNION ALL

SELECT *
FROM questions
WHERE examid = 15
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4;
```

This is my query and also i try this code. Is it possible to do that maybe i am not sure that union is worked or not for mysql.Mainly problem is random value one table get 1 and another table get 4 (that's my logic). How i do that

```
SELECT *
FROM v_fixed_questions vf
    ,v_questions vq ON (vf.examid = vq.examid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is that to use `LIMIT` with a union it needs to be in actual subquery, and not at the outer level.  It is possible to use `LIMIT` at the end of a union query, but then it would apply to the entire union result set, and not to one of the subqueries.

```
(
    SELECT *
    FROM fixed_questions
    WHERE examid = 15
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 1
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT *
    FROM questions
    WHERE examid = 15
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 4
);
```

This answer assumes that the `fixed_questions` and `questions` tables have the same number of columns (ideally with the same type).  If not, then it might not make sense to ask for a union of the two full tables.

Comment: @hasan_007 Perhaps open a new question.